# How can I start this image perfectly centered with this situation?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, positioning

I am animating an image from the exact center to a specific position in the top left. To do this, I need to use an absolute positioning. However, in the following situation, it does not start out centered. A solution to this would be making the position relative, but then the animation does not work. And if I do something like **left: 35%**, it is only centered on MY screen. How can I fix this issue?

```
<style>
#Intro {
position: relative;
height:100%;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

#Picture {
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
    var pos = $('#Picture').position();
    $('#Picture').css({
        top: pos.top + 'px',
        left: pos.left + 'px'
    }).fadeIn(1000).delay(1500).animate({
        'top': '25px',
        'left': '20px',
        'height': '101px'
    }, 2000, 'swing');
});
</script>

<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="4.5; URL=home.html">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="Intro">
<img src="images/Triplid Logo.png" id="Picture"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/UqMPC/

Comment: That's odd... That is not what happens. For me it starts 30% from the top, and it the left margin is at the center, not the center of the image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UqMPC/1/ As you can see, the image starts to the right of center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to be hidden initially, fade in at the absolute center of the window, then shrink to the top left hand corner, then the following will do that.

Note the simple formula to set the initial position of the image, and the use of `display: none;` to hide the image initially.

CSS:

```
#Intro {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#Picture {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    var $img = $('#Picture');
    $img.css({
        left: ($(window).width() - $img.width()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $img.height()) / 2
    }).fadeIn(1000).delay(1500).animate({
        'top': '25px',
        'left': '20px',
        'height': '101px'
    }, 2000, 'swing');
});
```

jsFiddle proof: http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/67Z6K/1/

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way for me to raise it slightly?

Comment: Probably, but can you expand a bit on what you mean by "raise it"?

Comment: Just lift it a bit higher. I am experiencing this VERY odd problem with this- if I open up this page or refresh my browser, it still starts to the right of the center. However, when I go back in my web browser to the page, it starts in the exact middle....

Comment: Is that behaviour only visible on your page, or on the jsFiddle link I posted as well? Also, what browser is this on? My best guess is that it is something to do with caching by the browser. Try changing `$(window).ready()` to `$(document).ready()` or just `$(function() { ... }` and see if it helps at all.